# Excel VBA: User defined function based on checkbox input not recalculating

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, excel-2013

In Excel 2013, I have defined a custom function `CUSTOM_EQUITY` which returns `"EXTERNAL"` or `"INTERNAL"` based on whether a checkbox (form control) is checked or not. It works okay when I press enter, but it doesn't auto-update when I click the checkbox, checking or unchecking it.

Forcing the update with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> works perfectly, but I'm unable to make the cell automatically update when the checkbox is clicked. As you see I have already tried with `Application.Volatile`.

```
Function CUSTOM_EQUITY()

    Application.Volatile
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Dim taxesExt As Boolean
    taxesExt = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TAXES_EXT").ControlFormat.Value = 1

    If taxesExt Then
        CUSTOM_EQUITY = "EXTERNAL"
    Else
        CUSTOM_EQUITY = "INTERNAL"
    End If

End Function
```

How can I make my function automatically recalculate when the checkbox value changes?

Comment: Have you considered calling the function's recalculation on the `Change` event of the `CheckBox`?

Comment: I would suggest linking checkbox to a cell, and using simple IF formula instead of VBA UDF.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks, `ActiveSheet.Calculate` on the `Change` event did the trick.

Comment: @user3964075 I need to use a UDF, the provided code was just a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are talking about a **CheckBox in a UserForm**, but if you are just place this line in the `CheckBox_Change()` :

```
Sheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Calculate
```

And if it is an **Excel CheckBox** :

1. Add a linked cell (here is in C1)
2. Place this in the Worksheet module

This code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
      'Nothing
    Else
       Sheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Calculate
    End If    
End Sub
```